# Asp.net core url re-writing from middleware not working

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a dot net core web application with some mvc controllers and an angular 2 app. I am trying to re-write request paths like "www.example.com/old/path" to "www.example.com/new/path" and then send it to the angular 2 app (which has routing setup only for "new/path"). But Angular keeps getting the old path even though re-writing seems to have worked (judging from breakpoints). I suspect this might reflect some kind of gap in my understanding of the order of middleware execution (but I have tried different orders and spamming the re-writing code everywhere to no avail).

This is how the url re-writing middleware looks like (UrlRewritingMiddleware.cs):

```
public sealed class UrlRewritingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    private readonly string OldPathSegment= "/old/path/";
    private readonly string NewPathSegment= "/new/path/";

    public UrlRewritingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
      this._next = next;
    }

    private void RewriteUrl(HttpContext context)
    {
      if (context.Request.Path.Value.IndexOf(OldPathSegment, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
      {
        context.Request.Path = new PathString(Regex.Replace(context.Request.Path.Value, OldPathSegment, NewPathSegment, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
      }
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
      RewriteUrl(context);
      await _next.Invoke(context);
      if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
      {
        context.Request.Path = "/app/root/index.html";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        await _next.Invoke(context);
        RewritePathsInContext(context);//spam
      }
      else
      {
        //spam
        RewritePathsInContext(context);
      }         
    }
}
```

And then this is how the Startup.cs Configure method looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //putting in the beginning, I get error in angular
    //EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/old/path'
    app.UseUrlRewritingMiddleware();
    app.AnotherCustomMiddleware();//I can see Path changed to new/path inside here
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    //putting this at the end gives me 404 in asp.net
    //app.UseUrlRewritingMiddleware();        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a good night's sleep I realized that server side re-writing of the request path is not going to change the url that shows up in the browser (which is what angular gets). So www.example.com/old/path is going to remain the same in the browser and only a redirect can change it to www.example.com/new/path (which is not what I want). To solve the issue I had to add redirects in the angular app itself. My angular app also calls some mvc controllers/ views but they are always in the /new/path format so I don't need server side re-writing at this point.

<s>Also, about the order of middlewares I suspect the reason putting it at the end gave me a 404 in asp.net might be because it comes after the UseMvc middleware (which already sets up routes?). Haven't tested it but as long as it comes before the UseMvc middleware, I think it should work.</s> **EDIT:** See ssmith's comment below. UseMvc is a terminal middleware so anything after it won't work.

If you do need server side url re-writing, asp.net core has a [re-writing middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting) that you can use and don't actually need to write your own:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
                 .AddRewrite(@"/old/path/", "/new/path/", skipRemainingRules: true);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: If you put middleware after UseMvc, it won't be hit. MVC is terminating. If MVC doesn't find something, it returns a 404 rather than calling the 'next' middleware.

Comment: also this might be useful to you (but won't help with the angular side of things): http://ardalis.com/using-custom-middleware-to-record-and-fix-404s-in-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: Ah, thanks ssmith. That clears up a few things :) Editing the answer to include the info you provided